# What is the best way to access custom functions in coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

I'm wondering if anyone has thoughts on what they think the best way to store and access custom function in coldfusion.

**What I'm currently doing:** At the moment I have a variety of CF-Components in which I store related functions. For example:

```
    <cfcomponent displayname="Math">
        <cffunction name="func1">
            <!---Code--->
        </cffunction>

        <!---Function 2, Function 3, etc.---->
    </cfcomponent>
```

Then when I need to use them on a page I do the following

```
    <cfset lv_math_obj = createobject("component","cfc.Math")>
    <cfset variable = lv_math_obj.myFunction(parameter)>
```

**Why I Like It:** The above code is easy to read and understand, and my functions are precompiled!

**Why I dislike it:** Objects are not supposed to be a list of functions that work independently of one another.

Has anyone thought of a better way to store and access custom functions?

Comment: There's also <cfproperty>.  Is your complaint that you have a bunch of <cffunction>'s, none of which read or alter any <cfproperty>'s?  Or is it that the functions really are independent, and you are just looking for the OO pattern for a repository of independent functions?

Comment: functions are precompiled? hmm, they're all precompiled, even if you define one inline in your .cfm afaik.

Comment: I've seen it done several ways - CFC like you describe, .cfm include like utilities.cfm or udf.cfm, and in a .cfm itself. I prefer having them in a separate file for re-usability, but I'm not sure that one way is "better" than another.

Comment: CFC does not necessarily mean 'object'. Using a CFC as a library of functions is a perfectly acceptable use. I often have a CFC with related functionality, such as Formatter.cfc to format dates, times, etc consistently, in an application. Also, what you are referring to are User Defined Functions (UDFs) not 'custom functions. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're currently doing has nothing wrong per-se, but for each request you're instantiating `cfc.Math` which shouldn't break a sweat in CF9+, but not necessary.

You can optimize it by instantiate once in `onApplicationStart()` and put the object into the `Application` scope.  However, doing so would make invoking an UDF rather verbose, i.e. `Application.math.func1()`.  You may set `Variables.math = Application.math` in `onRequest()` then all your CFM will have access to `math.anyFunc()`.  To make your UDFs accessible to any CFC methods you can consider putting the UDFs in `Form` or `Url` scope to get away with needing to use scope prefix.

Furthermore, when your `cfc.Math` is updated, you'd need to flush out the old copy by doing what most frameworks do (e.g. `?init=true`, detects that in `onRequestStart()`, and carry out the re-initialization), or restart the application.

IMO the simplest way would be putting the UDFs into a `math.cfm` and include it before I need to use them.

Comment: I think it would be easier to put the functions in a CFC and store it in a shared scope  - most likely application scope and more than likely by using ColdSpring, this way you can use the functions in your service tier as well as in any 'view' files (speaking from an MVC standpoint)

Answer (score 0):

You can place often used functions in the request scope.

```
<cffunction name="OnRequestStart" access="public" returntype="boolean" output="false">
    <cfargument name="TargetPage" type="string" required="true"/>
    <cfinclude template="/udfs/global.cfm">
    <cfreturn true />
</cffunction>
```

I find this very easy to work with. It is also possible to place the component or functions in the application scope but as Henry pointed out this can be really annoying when you are developing or changing a website.

If you place your functions in the request scope you need to make a reference to the function. For example the included /udfs/global.cfm file could contain the following function:

```
<cffunction name="func1">
<!---Code--->
</cffunction>
<cfset request.func1 = func1>
```

In the application you can call this function with the following statement:

```
<cfset test = request.func1()>
```